# HandleCheckBox react checked and unchecked , get a list into a state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have a long list of checkboxes (not that optimised) and I want to get them in a state(the checked one) and I'm not really sure how to handle it hope for help(should also handle uncheck when clicked)...

```html
              <div className=' row float-center d-flex justify-content-center '>
                <label className='m-3'>
                  <input
                    name='1'
                    type='checkbox'
                    checked={this.state.isGoing}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                  />
                  1
                </label>
                <label className=' m-3'>
                  <input
                    name='1.5'
                    type='checkbox'
                    checked={this.state.isGoing}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                  />
                  1.5
                </label>
              </div>
```

Comment: please elaborate on your question. What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you wish to store the information about the checkbox if it is checked or not into a state?

Comment: take the answer given below

Answer (score 1):

```
class Human extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checkState: {
        isGoing1: false,
        isGoing2: false
      }
    };
  }

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      checkState: {
        ...this.state.checkState,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.checked
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className=" row float-center d-flex justify-content-center ">
        <label className="m-3">
          <input
            name="isGoing1"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.isGoing1}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          1
        </label>
        <label className=" m-3">
          <input
            name="isGoing2"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.isGoing2}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          1.5
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isGoing1: false, isGoing2: false };
    this.handleInputChange1 = this.handleInputChange1.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange2 = this.handleInputChange2.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isGoing1: false });
    this.setState({ isGoing2: false });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({ isGoing1: false });
    this.setState({ isGoing2: false });
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log("isGoing1" + this.state.isGoing1);
    console.log("isGoing2" + this.state.isGoing2);
  }

  handleInputChange1 = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isGoing1: !state.isGoing1
    }));
  };
  handleInputChange2 = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isGoing2: !state.isGoing2
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className=" row float-center d-flex justify-content-center ">
        <label className="m-3">
          <input
            name="1"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.isGoing1}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange1}
          />
          1
        </label>
        <label className=" m-3">
          <input
            name="1.5"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.state.isGoing2}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange2}
          />
          1.5
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dw9ff6

Comment: Thats not a good solution because i don't want to create a new state for every checkbox.i want one state with a list checkboxes: [].

Comment: how will one know how many checkboxes you want? if we take that then we would just be needing to iterate over them by map but the logic is pretty simple in this

Comment: i will want like 20 checkboxes with just bigger numbers. so this solution is not optimal.

Comment: you should have created components